# Hosting a GCP instance on a WP Subdomain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, subdomain, dns-hosting

I have a custom domain (mydomain.com) hosted on Wordpress.com. I also have a Mautic instance hosted on Google Cloud (GCP). How do I make my Mautic instance ride on a subdomain (mautic.mydomain.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your config correctly, then you can find full instruction [here](https://wordpress.com/support/domains/map-subdomain/):

> At WordPress.com
> Go to your Domains page (My Site → Manage → Domains) and click the domain you wish to add the subdomain to.
> Click Name Servers and DNS, then DNS Records.
> In Type select CNAME or A.
> Enter the subdomain you want in Name.
> Enter the information provided from the service you’re trying to connect to under Alias Of (for CNAME) or Points To (for A Records).
> For example for Tumblr sites, you’ll need something like this:
> tumblr alias of domains.tumblr.com
> Click Add New DNS Record

In your case, you should input as follows:

**Type**
`A`

**Name**
`mautic`

**Points to**
`mautic deployment IP`

You can find IP of mautic deployment in GCP → Compute Engine → VM Instances → External IP

Comment: To Mr. Rusiecki: THANK YOU SO MUCH for your time and effort in replying to my question!